# Select TOP 1 * from Table Fails in Sybase Procedure

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase, sybase-asa

Am trying to Fetch Only one record from the Sybase Table without using the RowCount Function, even though "WHERE Condition" returns multiple results.

```
SELECT TOP 1 EMPLOYEE_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEEID > 50
```

Runs Successfully with one Record Only,

However

```
SELECT TOP 1 EMPLOYEE_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEEID > 50
```

fails, when written inside a Sybase Procedure as a Sub Query

Comment: What's the error? Can you show us the code?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Was this for [tag:sybase-asa] or [tag:sybase-ase]? You've tagged it with both....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Top is supported only in outer query only, here is the [link](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00641.1502/html/nfg1502/CHEHFFJJ.htm)

For ordered data I am using having cause instead Top 1 in Sybase, like:

```
SELECT  EMPLOYEE_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEEID > 50 HAVING EMPLOYEEID = MIN(EMPLOYEEID)
```

I hope it helps a bit. GL!

Answer (score -2):

I know it is late but just for others TOP inside a subquery can be used in sybase latest version.

Comment: Does not work for me. This question is about Sybase ASE. Can you give a link?